# php mail() function dont work with current year

Tags: php, email

I have this issue with my `mail()` function in my php form. It works fine, but when I add '2013' to the subject, the email is not delivered.

```
$subject = 'New WX Woman';  // Works
$subject = 'New 1111 WX Woman';  // Works
$subject = 'New 2022 WX Woman';  // Works
$subject = 'New 1022 WX Woman';  // Works
$subject = 'New 2013 WX Woman';  // Dont Work!!!

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {...
```

Any idea what could be causing my problem?

UPDATE [CODE WITH HEADERS]

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'New 2022 WX Woman';
$headers = 'From: WX Woman of the Year <info@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message .= '</body></html>';

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo("success");
} else {
echo("fail");
}
```

Comment: Bizarre indeed. Can we see where your $headers variable is built? That's usually the culprit in troubleshooting `mail()` function breakdowns (in my experience)

Comment: Are you sure the message isn't in your spam folder?

Comment: That sounds like a spam filter to me.

Comment: The presence of the current (or adjacent) year in the subject is a good spam flag, I think Marcel's right.

Comment: `var_dump` result of `mail` function. Is it `true` or `false` when you send letter with 2013 year?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to mail header injection; never trust user content. Check for validness of the `$_POST['req-email']` mail address using [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) and *only* if it's valid, send the mail. Otherwise it's easy to inject extra headers like `Bcc` and send spam to many others; `strip_tags` won't prevent this.

Comment: Fixed the errors, it was going to my spam, thanks @MarcelKorpel